# Step by step guide to deploy a Spring Boot micro service to local Kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to make some experiments with Kubernetes to possibly use it for our project.

Reading the documents and watching the presentations, I have seen that one possible/common set up is Vagrant+CoreOS+Kubernetes.

So, I followed the steps listed here:
https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-vagrant.html

Looks like my environment is working fine.

But after that, I could not find any documentation about how to deploy a simple Spring Boot RestAPI to that environment. 
Do you know any documentation/step by step guide for deploying a web service to local Kubernetes environment?

Comment: Look at the docker documentation and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

The roundabout steps now that you have a cluster are to package your app into a docker image, then deploy that to the k8s cluster. From there you'll want to expose the pods to the system via services.

Have a look at this video from SpringOne last year: https://spring.io/blog/2015/10/19/springone2gx-2015-replay-spring-boot-micro-services-containers-and-kubernetes-how-to

Answer (score 0):

Well deploying spring boot application to local kubernetes cluster can be broken down in to 3 steps

**Step-1 : Setup local kubernetes cluster** - I guess which you already did. But if havn't done then you can follow this guide - [Step by step guide for setting up kubernetes cluster](https://jhooq.com/kubespray-12-steps-for-installing-a-production-ready-kubernetes-cluster/)

**Step-2 : Created docker image and upload to DockerHub** - [Click here for the steps](https://jhooq.com/deploy-spring-boot-microservices-on-kubernetes/#step-5-docker-hub)

**Step-3 : Deploy spring boot docker image on Kubernetes Cluster** - [Click here for the steps](https://jhooq.com/deploy-spring-boot-microservices-on-kubernetes/#step-9-k8s-cluster-deploy)

For deploy Spring boot application on Google Kubernetes Engine(GKE), please refer to the guide  - [**Step by Step guide to deploy Spring Boot On Google Kubernetes Engine(GKE)**](https://jhooq.com/deploy-spring-boot-microservices-on-kubernetes/#part-2)